# Recorrer array que se muestra vació, pero tiene elementos

Tags: javascript, array

[image: Contenido del array]

Como podéis ver, el array que muestro por consola muestra elementos/objetos, pero no puedo recorrerlos ni obtenerlos por su indice, he probado forEach, Array[0] y mucho mas, pero no puedo llegar a sus elementos, usando length dice que es 0 y así entre otras opciones utilizadas...

Este array es llenado por un ajax y pasado a una variable "global" (var Array = new Array), cuando recorro el Json los elementos/objetos están bien, solo que al consultar la variable fuera del proceso de ajax, se convierte en el array que podéis ver, la duda aquí es como proceder a los elementos de tal array.

Lo siguiente es el código del Ajax obteniendo la respuesta de la consulta;

```
var UnoNuevoPadre = new Array;
var PermitidosAgrupacion;

var dsa = nuevoAjax();
dsa.open("POST", "Control.php", true);
dsa.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
dsa.send('action=obtenerAgrupacion');
dsa.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(dsa.readyState == 4){
        PermitidosAgrupacion = JSON.parse(dsa.response);
        PermitidosAgrupacion.forEach(function(element){
           var Agrupacion = element['agrupacion'].toLowerCase();
           UnoNuevoPadre.push(Agrupacion);

        });

    }
}
console.log(UnoNuevoPadre);
```

Comment: añade el código de tu array como texto para poder reproducir el ejercicio

Comment: Ya estaría la sección del código que genera el array...

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si mueves el `console.log` dentro del `if` justo después de tu `.forEach`?

Comment: Por consola obtengo el array de: ["compras", "mantenedores", "ventas"], si es puesto fuera del if, dará 3 vueltas, las primeras 2 serian Arrays igual que el del caso y el ultimo viene a ser el Array antes consultado.

Comment: El objeto UnoNuevoPadre es el que tiene los valores ["compras", "mantenedores", "ventas"]  y es el que quieres recorrer??, si es así, no veo en tu código ningún forEach sobre UnoNuevoPadre

Comment: No puedo hacerle un forEach como dije en el tema al array, simplemente no hace nada....

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN,

- Lo he podido solucionar

> *notification[0]?.cliente.nombre*

Solo debes poner el signo de interrogación para indicarle que ese objeto puede o no llegar vacio, esto sucede por que la ASICRONÍA DE AJAX, al ser ASINCRONO, por defecto tiene la condición "Posiblemente null" por lo tanto si intentas acceder a sus elementos puede que aún no existan en el array, con el signo de interrogación de dices a JavaScript que si no existe aun, lo espere y cuando este llegue lo pinte en pantalla o sea utilizable

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: La otra respuesta que agregaste en realidad es una nueva pregunta. Recuerda que el formato de [es.so] es de _una pregunta y sus respuestas_: haz el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio. No olvides borrar la _no-respuesta_.